# Trying to deference a pointer back into a structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

basically i'm trying to implement an array of linked list and i'm having problems trying to remove the first node and replacing it with the next node because it is a pointer.

```
typedef struct BLOCKSTRUCT{
    int address;       //starting address
    struct BLOCKSTRUCT* next;
    int status;
} block;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tSize = 10;
    block *arr = (block*)malloc(sizeof(block) * tSize);
    // other code in between

    if(arr[size].next != NULL)
    {
        arr[size] =  &arr[size].next; // Having problems with this line
    }

}
```

I have tried the following:

- arr[size] =  &arr[size].next;
- arr[size] =  (block)arr[size].next;
- &arr[size] =  arr[size].next;

but i'm getting the following errors:

- Invalid initializer
- Conversion to non-scalar type requested
- Incompatible types in assignment

Would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to overcome this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: It's not quite clear what your linked list looks like. What you show is only an array of 10 structs. You probably use those as a pool, but deleting stuff from the linkes list does not assign new data to the nodes; it only means rearranging the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the contents of what the pointer `next` points at.

```
arr[size] = *arr[size].next;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked ! 
Quite new to C syntax here :)

Answer (score 0):

`*` can be used to deference a pointer

Try

```
    arr[size] =  *arr[size].next;
```

[Further reading material](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf)